# Banner notification of Webby Awards

Tags: support, notifications

I followed the banner notification and casted my vote.

However, the notification still pops up everytime I open Stack Overflow. Is there a way to switch off the notification?

***Note:*** I am on Google Chrome, Windows 10, Desktop.

Comment: Try voting for one of the other sites who have less annoying notification banners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at the code, I'm not sure if clicking the link is supposed to dismiss the banner (and we have a bug) or if it's behaving as intended (and we possibly have a UX issue?)... but either way, clicking the X over on the right should take care of it:

[image: screenshot of the banner with the dismiss X button on the right]

If *that* is broken, then we definitely have a bug on our hands.

Comment: FWIW, I clicked on x and I don't see the banner anymore (I even logged from another computer). So, I would assume that part is not broken.